# php json_encode doesn't give pure object

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is probaly a really easy question but am struggling with this four about 2 hours now.

I have a php file:

```
$array = array(
        "id"=> 1, "firstName"=> "James", "lastName"=> "King", "managerId"=> 0, "managerName"=> "", "title"=> "President and CEO", "department"=> "Corporate", "cellPhone"=> "617-000-0001", "officePhone"=> "781-000-0001", "email"=> "jking@fakemail.com", "city"=> "Boston, MA", "pic"=> "James_King.jpg", "twitterId"=> "@fakejking", "blog"=> "http://coenraets.org"
    );
echo json_encode($array);
```

Now I want to give this an object like the following:

```
Object
blog: "http://coenraets.org"
cellPhone: "617-000-0001"
city: "Boston, MA"
department: "Corporate"
email: "jking@fakemail.com"
firstName: "James"
id: 1
lastName: "King"
managerId: 0
managerName: ""
officePhone: "781-000-0001"
pic: "James_King.jpg"
title: "President and CEO"
twitterId: "@fakejking"
```

Right now i'm getting the following response:

```
abort: (a)

always: ()

complete: ()

done: ()

error: ()

....

readyState: 4

responseText: "{"id":1,"firstName":"James","lastName":"King","managerId":0,"managerName":"","title":"President and CEO","department":"Corporate","cellPhone":"617-000-0001","officePhone":"781-000-0001","email":"jking@fakemail.com","city":"Boston, MA","pic":"James_King.jpg","twitterId":"@fakejking","blog":"http:\/\/coenraets.org"}"

setRequestHeader: (a,b)

state: ()

... 

__proto__: Object
```

I really don't know where to look and am probaly doing something wrong but I really have no idea.

UPDATE

js

```
var result = $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost/cordova/employees/index.php?name="+ searchKey,
          context: document.body
        });
    console.log(JSON.parse(result.responseText));
```

The line console.log(JSON.parse(result.responseText)) gives me the following error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

Comment: The response text is your JSON object. The rest of the stuff is the context around the request that was made.

Comment: Did you set you header type?

Comment: What does your JavaScript code look like?

Comment: I have added the js code

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're looking at the XMLHttpRequest object. You need to parse out the response to get the object.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

where `xhr` is the name of the object you're doing a `console.log` on.

Comment: If I add this I get an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u              Sometimes u other times o

Comment: @user3398922 Make sure you're passing in the correct data. You are probably passing it `undefined` instead of the correct string from `responseText`. This would be a lot easier if you showed how you printed out the result in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax()` makes an asynchronous HTTP request, so you can't just get the response right way. You have to wait for the response to come to you. The [done()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) construct can be used to fire a callback when your response is ready.

```
var getEmployee = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/cordova/employees/index.php?name="+ searchKey,
    context: document.body,
    dataType: 'json'
});
// the callback will get fired when the response is received
getEmployee.done(function (result) {
    console.log(result.blog);
});
// this will get fired immediately before the response is even received
console.log(getEmployee.responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple feature.
read about stdClass in PHP
and modify your php code to:

```
$array = new stdClass();
$array->id = 1;
$array->firstName = "James";
//..... other fields
echo json_encode($array);
```